# React Native DatePickerIOS Rotate Back to Old Date

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, datepicker

I'm Using DatePickerIOS in React native **after Change Date of DatePickerIOS the Wheel is Rotate Back To Old Date** but in alert Display New Date.

I want to Set New Date and remove Wheel Rotate Back to old Date Issue.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, DatePickerIOS, Text} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

var moment = require('moment');

const DatePickerIOSExample = (props) => {

    state = {
        stateDate: new Date(),
    }

    changeDate = (date) => {
        this.setState = ({
            stateDate:date
        })
        alert(this.setState.stateDate);
    }

    const {navigate} = props.navigation;
    return(
        <View>
            <DatePickerIOS 
                date={this.state.stateDate} 
                onDateChange={this.changeDate.bind(this)} 
                mode="date" />

            <Text>{moment(this.state.stateDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY')}</Text>
        </View>
    );
}

export default DatePickerIOSExample;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating on abject "setState" and not calling setState.

The correct way is:

```
changeDate = (date) => {
    this.setState({
        stateDate:date
    })
    alert(this.state.stateDate);
}
```

As you can see I have removed the "=" after "setState" and I have change the alert content "this.state.stateDate" (so you are accessing the state).

Important: remember that setState is asynchronous (https://medium.com/@wereHamster/beware-react-setstate-is-asynchronous-ce87ef1a9cf3)

Comment: it is Work After Change another change **const DatePickerIOSExample** change to **class DatePickerIOSExample extends Component** and return inside the **render() { **